# document is not defined

Tags: javascript, ejs

estoy creando una página con html, css, js y EJS para poder hacer templates que después agrego con la función include. Hasta ahí pude hacerlo bien, pero se me complicó cdo quise incluir en el index.js el código para tener una navbar responsive con menu y submenu.

Seguí un video que vi, así que en teoría el código está bien, pero cdo actualizo chrome después de hacer el código en Js, me aparece el error:  document is not defined.

Tengo un archivo navbar.ejs en el que tengo el partial para el navbar y un footer.ejs en el que tengo el partial del footer y por eso ahí está el  Lo raro es que en index.js no me deja poner ni un alert(); si lo hago tb me tira el mismo error diciendo que alert is not defined.
Sé que es complejo, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

```js
//Express y rutas
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const path = require ('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about')
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))


//Animando el menu

const btnMenu = document.querySelector("#btnMenu");
const opciones = document.querySelector("#opciones");
btnMenu.addEventListener("click", function(){
    opciones.classList.toggle("mostrar");
});


const submenu_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".submenu_btn");
for(let i=0; i < submenu_btn.length; i++) {
    submenu_btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 1024){
            const submenu = this.nextElementSibling;
            const height = submenu.scrollHeight;

            if(submenu.classList.contains("desplegar")){
                submenu.classList.remove("desplegar");
                submenu.removeAttribute("style");
            } else {
            submenu.classList.add("desplegar");
            submenu.style.height = height + "px";
            }
        }
    });
}
*/

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("consoling on port 3000");
})
```

```css
.nav-bar{
    display: block;
    background:#EECB71;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.opciones_menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: -100%;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.mostrar{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.submenu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.opciones_menu{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}

.menu_link{
    color: #EECB71;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0.7rem;
}

.menu_link:hover{
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

.submenu{
    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding-left: 1.2rem;
}

.logo img{
    width: 2rem;
    height: auto;
}

.busqueda{
    background-color: #EECB71;
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 6rem;
    height: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    border: 1px solid black;  
}

#formB{
    height: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


#search{
    height: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #EECB71;  
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
    width: 4.5rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}


#submit{
    width: 0.8rem;
    height: 0.8rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

#reset{
    display: none;
}


@media(min-width:1024px) {
    .nav-bar{
        display: none;
    }

    .opciones_menu{
        margin-left: 0;
        display: flex;
        
    }

    .submenu_container{
        position: relative;
    }

    .submenu{
        position: absolute;
        width: 7.7rem;
        top: 100%;
        overflow: visible;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .submenu_container:hover .submenu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="nav-bar" id="btnMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>

<nav class="main_nav">
    
    <menu> 
        
        <ul class="opciones_menu" id="opciones">
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="about" class="menu_link">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"> <a href="" class="menu_link">LEE MIS LIBROS</a></li>         
            
            <span><img src="./logo.png" alt=""></span>

            <li class="menu_item submenu_container">
                <a href="#" class="menu_link submenu_btn">ESTUVIMOS EN <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a> <!--VER SI APARECE LA FLECHA Y TODOS LOS ICONOS-->
                <ul class="submenu"> 
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="" class="menu_link">SUDAMÉRICA</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="" class="menu_link">ASIA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="" class="menu_link">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
       
    </menu>
    <div class="busqueda">
        <form id="formB" action="">
            <input  id="search" type="search required"/>
            <button type="reset" id="reset"></button>
            <button type="submit" id="submit"><i id="lupa" class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Estás mezclando código de node con código de javascript en el front. No es lo mismo. Uno se ejecuta en el servidor y otro se ejecuta en el navegador. En el servidor no existe `document` ni `alert` ni nada que tenga que ver con el DOM.

Comment: Para solucionarlo tienes varias vías, pero de manera rápida, copia todo el código que tiene que ver con la animación del menú y ponlo al final del body en tu `ejs` en una etiqueta script `<script>..Codigo..</script>`

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime. Recién hoy pude retomar el trabajo y con tu respuesta quedó solucionado. Gracias!!